# Samsung Galaxy S7 show device photos rotated

Tags: android, galaxy, mediastore

I've developed an android app that shows in an adaptor all photos the user has in its device.

This is the code I'm using to read the photos:

```
    Cursor photos;
    String pictureCols[] = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME };
    String order = Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC";
    photos = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, pictureCols, null, null, order);
    photos.moveToFirst();
photosAdapter.addItems(photos);
```

And inside the adapter this is the code I use to show them:

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View gridView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        gridView = new View(context);
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_item, null);
    }
    else
    {
        gridView = (View) convertView;
    }

    photoIV = (SquareImageView)gridView.findViewById(R.id.photo);

    long photoId = photos.getLong(0);
    String thumbURL = "file://"+photos.getString(1);
    String thumbCols[] = { MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA };
    Cursor thumbCursor = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.queryMiniThumbnail(context.getContentResolver(), photoId, Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, thumbCols);
    if(thumbCursor.getCount() > 0) {
        thumbCursor.moveToFirst();
        thumbURL = "file://"+thumbCursor.getString(1);
    }
    thumbCursor.close();

    if(!thumbURL.equals(""))
    {
       mImageOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
            .build();

        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(thumbURL, photoIV, mImageOptions);
   }

    return gridView;
}
```

This code is working OK on all devices I've tested so far but some users with Samsung Galaxy S7 have reported that most of their photos are shown rotated. I cannot find any documentation related to this issue in S7. Has S7 changed something related to this? Should I read the photos in a different way to get their correct orientation? This code has been working for a long time in a lot of devices.

Comment: "This code is working ok on all devices I've tested so far" -- it will fail for any photo stored on removable storage on Android 4.4+ devices (as you do not have direct filesystem access to the photo) and where the `MediaStore` is not giving you access to a thumbnail via a filesystem path that you can use. "some users with Samsung Galaxy S7 have reported that most of their photos are shown rotated" -- perhaps whatever `ImageLoader` is doing does not involve examining EXIF headers to see if the image should be rotated.

Comment: Regarding to access to removable storage I'll study how to access those photos. Regarding ImageLoader, I've edited my post to show the options I'm using. I'm not sure if ImageLoader is the problem because if this library doesn't take into account EXIF headers I guess it would be failing in all devices and this is not the case.

Comment: "I guess it would be failing in all devices" -- no, it would be failing on those devices that rely on EXIF orientation headers. Not all do. Some actually rotate the image. It varies by camera hardware.

Comment: Thanks! @CommonsWare, you point me in the right direction, it was due to ImageLoader, once I set its option considerExifParams(true) all photos were shown correctly. I would like to vote you as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an image-loading library, and you care about EXIF orientation headers, choose an image-loading library that applies those headers for you (e.g., Picasso, at least for local images). This may require some sort of an opt-in call (e.g., `considerExifParams(true)`, per your comment).

Not all images will have an EXIF orientation header. It depends on whether it is a photo, what sort of camera hardware took the photo, whether the camera app that took the photo rotated the image for you, etc.